# How to send SOL in Solana NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, solana

The documentation shows how to make a transfer from one wallet to another. In one account.

```C#
// Initialize the rpc client and a wallet
var rpcClient = ClientFactory.GetClient(Cluster.TestNet);
var wallet = new Wallet();
// Get the source account
var fromAccount = wallet.GetAccount(0);
// Get the destination account
var toAccount = wallet.GetAccount(1);
// Get a recent block hash to include in the transaction
var blockHash = rpcClient.GetRecentBlockHash();

// Initialize a transaction builder and chain as many instructions as you want before building the message
var tx = new TransactionBuilder().
        SetRecentBlockHash(blockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash).
        SetFeePayer(fromAccount).
        AddInstruction(MemoProgram.NewMemo(fromAccount, "Hello from Sol.Net :)")).
        AddInstruction(SystemProgram.Transfer(fromAccount, toAccount.GetPublicKey, 100000)).
        Build(fromAccount);

var firstSig = rpcClient.SendTransaction(tx);
```

How to make a transfer to another account?
Do I need to know the private key of the account to which I will transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has all of the pieces you need.  To transfer to another account, you need to create a transaction (using `TransactionBuilder`), and specifically add a `SystemProgram.Transfer` instruction to your transaction.  Also, in your example, you're sending from `fromAccount`, which has the private key, to `toAccount.PublicKey`.  You're using the `PublicKey` of `toAccount`, so no need for the private key of the recipient.

Note that the example appears to be incorrect, so you should base your code from this example instead: https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/blob/8369ac166ed90a7e6b07060178ed70745bd97bc3/src/Solnet.Examples/TransactionBuilderExample.cs#L22